# socket.io not log console message

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

My local app loads and everything run fine, but I can not get the terminal to log my connection console message `a user connected`.

```
  var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  server = require('http').createServer(app),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

  io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');
  });

  server.listen(3000);
```

the only thing i get is:

> info  - socket.io started
>   debug - served static content /socket.io.js

help? suggestion? ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested code, from a previous project that I worked on:

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

var io = require('http').Server(app);
var socket = require('socket.io')(io);

socket.on('connect',function(socket){
    console.log('got a connection')
});

io.listen(3000)
```

Please try if these changes work for you..

Comment: um - i get error when running it.... on *require('socket.io')(io)* - `TypeError: object is not a function`

Comment: I have a `socket.io` version `1.2.0`, and it works, just checked

Comment: Update: for node v5.1.0, socket io(v1.7.3) console logs not working. upgrade node to v5.12.0 get it working. kind of awkward though :)

Comment: For me it is not printing too. All other projects are printing. THe only ones under io.on() are not printing.